# Spring MVC: global exception handler

Tags: spring-mvc, exception

I want to implement some kind of global event handler but only for error logging purpose and without any redirection.

For example, the controller's method fails and my event handler will catch the exception (of any kind or specific type of exception) and does some logic and that's it. After that the controller's logic will continue. I checked the [ExceptionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) but it requires to return Model/Map or handle the response so it doesn't help me.

Is it possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever considered AOP for your requirement ? Use - After Throwing Advice.